# Process is coming out of for loop for IJson Iteams

Tags: python, ijson

I am using python 3.9 and trying :

```
with open(file, 'r') as fl:  
    val = ijson.items(fl, '<my_key>.item', use_float=True)
    for i in val:
        print(i)
```

After some time print statement is not printing anything on jupyter console, but that jupyte cell still run for a very long time.

Is it like, even if I parse specific elements, **ijson** scan complete file from start to end?, if **YES**, **how can i restrict this behaviour(if it is possible).**

Note: Instead of content->print am writing content->into some file, I can see file contents are not changing after some time, but process keeps running.
I have tried all sorts of closing file operations etc. Nothing work so far.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to break out of the ijson iteration is to break it yourself (i.e., actually `break` from the `for` loop). This is because, as you suggest, ijson goes through reads input files fully. This in turn is because your path (`<my_key>.item`) could appear again in your file after the initial set of results you are seeing (keys are not required to be unique in JSON).

Comment: Thanks, @Rodrigo Tobar.. So if i have more then one elemets for which i want to iterate, am actually reading file that many times, ?

Comment: I am unable to get control in loop itself, so I am unable do something like, break after 10000 records, irrespective of records , (less or more)

Comment: If you have to iterate over more than one list you'll have to use a lower-level procedure like `ijson.parse`.